# How to find Geolocation (longitude and latitude)in jquery mobile +phonegap

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

can you please tell me how to find Geo location (longitude and latitude) in jquery mobile using phonegap.And then i need to show the position on map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have referred [Phonegap's Getting Started Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/index.html) to create basic project.

This is the script to get Lattitude and Longitude

```
/*
 * This file contains script to get lattitude and longitude
 * 
 */
var lat = 0;
var lng = 0;
//A button click will call this function
function getLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy: true });
}

// onSuccess Geolocation
//
function onSuccess(position) {
    //Lat long will be fetched and stored in session variables
    //These variables will be used while storing data in local database 
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lng = position.coords.longitude;
    alert('Lattitude: ' + lat + ' Longitude: ' + long);
    sessionStorage.setItem('lattitude', lat);
    sessionStorage.setItem('longitude', lng);
}
// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

You will have to add necessary permissions in your **manifest** file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

Call `getLocation()` function onclick event of button or wherever you wish to get geolocation.

For more details refer [Phonegap Geolocation Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation)

To show google map please refer [Google MAP API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Getting the good demo .Can you please tell me how to show this latitude and longitude map..?

Comment: Glad that helped. I have mentioned a link for showing map in the above answer. To show google map please refer [**Google MAP API**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)